# Simple $R$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, division-algebras

Let $M$ be a simple $R$-module and $N=M\bigoplus M$. Then which one is true:

1) $N$ has a finite number of submodules.

2) $\operatorname{Hom}_R(N,N)$ is a division ring.

3) $\operatorname{Hom}_R(N,N)$ is isomorphic to a product of four division rings.

4) $J(R)N=0$.

Comment: Some help may come from the definition of simple $R$-module.

Comment: Suppose that R is a field. Can you answer there?

Comment: Let $\varphi \in \mathrm{Hom}_R(N,N)$ be $\varphi(x \oplus y) = x \oplus 0$.  Is $\varphi^{-1} \in \mathrm{Hom}_R(N,N)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a maximal ideal *m* of *R* s.t. $M=R/m$.
 $N$ has finite number submodules and as  Eric Towers said  inverse of $φ$  is not $1-1$ so $Hom_R(N,N)$ is not a division ring. $Hom_R(N,N)≅Hom_R(R/m⨁R/m,R/m⨁R/m)$. $J(R)N=0$ because $J(R)⊆m$ so $J(R). R/m=0$

Comment: $N$ can have infinitely many submodules.

Comment: @Jack Schmidt:pleas explain.

Comment: Take $R=\mathbb{R}$, $M=\mathbb{R}$, $N=\mathbb{R}^2$ has infinitely many subspaces.